# C While loop does not working

Tags: c, linux, while-loop

i'm beginner in C programming language, i have piece of code written in C language on linux Platform my code is :

```
  #include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

printf("Count Of Args %d \n",argc);

int i = 0;

while(i < argc){
printf("%s \n",argv[i]);
printf("loop N: %d \n",i);
i++;
}

return 0;

}
```

While loop does not working and i don't know why... please show me where is problem? thanks.

Comment: in what way does this not work?

Comment: Try posting (a) the output, and (b) your definition of "work".

Comment: "Not working" is an absolutely horrible description of the problem. What happens, and what do you expect to happen instead?

Comment: The code is fine. How are you compiling/running it? That's probably where your problem is.

Comment: Learn to perhaps indent your source file `mysrc.c`  with `indent mysrc.c`, compile it with warnings & debugging info with `gcc -Wall -g mysrc.c -o myprog`, improve it till you get no warnings. Then learn how to use the `gdb` debugger on your program: `gdb myprog`. You can run it step by step, display variables, etc..

Answer (score 4):

Works perfectly:

```
$ ./program abc def
Count Of Args 3 
./program 
loop N: 0 
abc 
loop N: 1 
def 
loop N: 2
```